# Why can't I set the default profile for AWS CLI in a Powershell session

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli

What am I doing wrong here?

My %UserProfile%.aws\config file looks like this:

```
[profile foo]
output = json
region = us-east-1
```

My %UserProfile%.aws\credentials file looks like this:

```
[foo]
aws_access_key_id = BAOAIGKMPRBTLBNOSCZQ
aws_secret_access_key = OcML0LadbbD3Nt+PmAlhzNTmoS6Xx9M3M6DkBx4m
```

So there is no default profile configured: I want to set only for the Powershell session.

In Powershell I run:

```
set AWS_PROFILE=foo
```

Then I try to execute a cli command, but it says it cannot find the credentials:

```
PS D:\> aws ec2 describe-instances
You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure".
PS D:\> aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

Comment: What does 'Write-Output $env:AWS_PROFILE'  show?

Comment: It printed nothing, which led me to the correct answer - thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Ah, I figured out that in Powershell you can't set environment variables using the `set` command. (Aside: I wonder what Powershell thinks it's doing when you use the `set` command... it doesn't give an error message).

The correct way is:

```
$env:AWS_PROFILE="foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with using multiple profiles for multiple clients, some of which refresh *every day*, and myself, so I wrote this function.

This doesn't require closing and reopening the console.

You can use the full profile name or the zero-based index of profiles [0-9]

For best results, remove the [default] profile and use this instead.

NOTE: I use `Set-Alias ~ (Get-Variable HOME).Value` for my HOME directory.

```
function Set-AwsProfile($prof){
    $creds = get-content ~/.aws/credentials 
    | select-string -Pattern "(?<=\[).*(?=\])"
    if($prof.Length -eq 1){
        $prof = $creds[$prof] -Replace "(\[|\])", ""
    }
    if($prof){
        $ENV:AWS_PROFILE = "$prof"
        $ENV:AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE = "$prof"
        aws configure list
    }else{
        $creds
    }
}
```